# Class methods in PHP

Tags: php, class-method

I am coming from the Ruby world and I have a PHP project I currently work on.

Like in Ruby scripts, is it possible to declare class methods in PHP? Basically, I'm asking what the equivalent of the following code would be in PHP

```
class A
  def hello; "hello from object"; end
  def self.hello; "hello from class"; end
end
```

Note the difference between the instance method and the class method.

Comment: A Google search for "PHP class" will definitely point you to the PHP manual, in particular the [Classes and objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) page!

Comment: I would refer you http://www.killerphp.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php/ if you are new to php.

Comment: I have read through the PHP docs in detail. Didn't seen to find anything to help

Comment: Thanks Vinay. I'll check that out now

Comment: @Yasky Did you miss this page in your reading: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: I probably did ( ._.) Moreso, I didn't realize static methods are the equivalent of class methods { ._.}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP class methods are usually referred to as static methods and are declared as such. To directly translate your example:-

```
class A
{
    public function hello()
    {
        return "hello from object";
    }

    //We can't have two methods with the same name.
    public static function s_hello()
    {
        return "hello from class";
    }
}
```

Then you would call the methods like this:-

```
//For a static method we don't need an instance
echo A::s_hello;
//But we do for an instance method
$a = new A();
echo $a->hello();
```

You can also have static properties, so the above example could be modified something like this:-

```
class A
{
    private static $s_hello = "hello from class";
    private $hello = "hello from object";

    public function hello()
    {
        return $this->hello;
    }

    //We can't have two methods with the same name.
    public static function s_hello()
    {
        return self::$hello;
    }
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I would suggest reading JohnDave's answer too. Both are very well written. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

```
class A
  def hello; "hello from object"; end
  def self.hello; "hello from class"; end
end

class A {
    // attributes or properties
    public $age; 
    private $gender; 
    protected $location; 
    // needs to be static to be called as self:: inside the class
    public static function hello(){
         return "hello from object";
    }
    // use this keyword to be called inside the class
    public function hello1(){
        return "hello from object";
    }
    public function hello2(){
         print(self::hello());
         print(this->hello1());
    }
    // How about private method
    private function hello3(){
         return "hello world";
    }
}

Calling Outside the class

$instance = new A();
//static
$instance::hello();
//non static
$instance->hello1();
$instance->hello2();
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at static methods: http://php.net/static

A static method is called like that:

```
Foo::aStaticMethod();
```

Comment: Without additional code within your static method it will not return different results depending on where it is called from.

Comment: @sabre: I didn't understand that his goal was to have two methods with the same name but only to know how to implement static methods.

Answer (score -2):

There is no way in php to have multiple definition of the same function in single class

rather you can do this

```
abstract class A{
 static function hello()
 {
   return 'hello';
 }
}

class B extends class A  
{
  function hello()
  {
  return 'hello from Object';
  }
}

A::hello();
$t = new B();
$t->hello();
```

Comment: Neither of those are static methods. The OP is asking about both static and instance methods.

Comment: And both of your examples are instance methods.

Comment: @vascowhite nothing stops them to be used as statics A::hello(): will no netter at all

Comment: @Rupshed:  E_STRICT: Calling non-static methods statically generates an E_STRICT level warning.

Comment: @RupeshPatel But you called them both from the object, not the class context. Also your misspelling of `echo` isn't helping your case.

Comment: @RupeshPatel That still isn't right. They both echo "hello from object".